# What is this plastic wrap used in electronics?

Tags: identification, plastic

I will occasionally receive electronic components from China tightly wrapped in this plastic film. It's much thicker than general plastic wrap that's bought from the store and does a good job at adhering to itself when wrapped.

I have tried wrapping the same parts using generic plastic wrap for food but it fails to adhere; providing a loose wrapping that will unspool itself.

Is this material something used in packaging? Does it have a name?

Is this possibly some kind of wrappable heat shrink?

[image]

Comment: Don't use that cling wrap for things like this; it generates a ton of static. I've never seen parts shipped like that, but I wouldn't trust that to be static safe...

Comment: why did you use the `heatsink` tag?

Comment: @jstola I thought it read "heatshrink". I've removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a kind of cling wrap. I bought a small roll of it last time I was the market in Shenzhen for a few CNY. From the photo you can see the color in bulk which is greenish compared to the water clear color of Glad Wrap type cling wraps. In thin layers it still looks clear.

I've seen similar stuff for sale here in industrial size lots for protecting acrylic sheets etc., but it's nice to be able to score small quantities.

[image]

Probably not static safe (I have not tested it) but good for holding little bits of hardware together.

Edit: Conductivity between probes less than 0.1nS so definitely not static safe.

Edit2: In fact, the way cling wrap works is that it **generates** static when you stretch it, which is what makes it stick to itself. So you can't have antistatic cling wrap. That's why another name of this material is **stretch wrap**, because you have to stretch it to make it work. You can buy it for wrapping pallets, for example.

Edit3: Oh, those are DIP packages. Didn't recognize them at first. That's not good.

Comment: Does it have a common name? Is it ever used with heat to form a tighter seal?

Comment: No, that's a completely different kind of plastic. Shrink wrap or shrink film. It's stretched at the factory and then when it goes through a heat tunnel or whatever it shrinks back towards it's original size. That's what used to be used on packaged software, for example. See my edits above.